# Filemode is not a member of io

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net

I am trying to use the code below to try and close a file stream because I am getting errors even after I dispose it that it is still in use on the server. So I thought maybe loop it until it is closed since it will not close after 1 try. Anyway I am getting the error that FileMode, File Access, FileShare is not a member of IO.?

```
Dim thisFileInUse As Boolean = False
    Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream

    If System.IO.File.Exists(sFile) Then
        Try
            fs = System.IO.File.Open(sFile, io.FileMode.Open, io.FileAccess.Write, io.FileShare.ReadWrite)
            fs.Close()
            fs.Dispose()
        Catch
            Try
                fs.Close()
                fs.Dispose()
            Catch

            End Try

            thisFileInUse = True
        End Try
    End If
    Return thisFileInUse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Imports System.IO


Dim thisFileInUse As Boolean = False
Dim fs As FileStream

If File.Exists(sFile) Then
    Try
        fs = File.Open(sFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)
 ...
```

`System.IO` is the namespace name, if you import it, you can avoid having to type it over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Finally` and the correct namespace `System.IO`:

```
Imports System.IO
' ....

Public Shared Function IsFileInUse(sFile As String) As Boolean
    Dim stream As FileStream = Nothing
    Dim isInUse As Boolean = False
    Try
        stream = File.Open(sFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
    Catch generatedExceptionName As IOException
        isInUse = True
    Finally
        If stream IsNot Nothing Then
            stream.Close()
        End If
    End Try
    Return isInUse
End Function
```